# Spring JPA @JoinColumn(unique = true) not working

Tags: spring, jpa

My entities are as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "t1",
    uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(name = "u1", columnNames = {"u1"}),
            @UniqueConstraint(name = "u2", columnNames = {"u2_id"}) //This does not enforce uniqueness
    }
)
public class t1
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String u1; //Uniqueness is enforced here

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(unique = true) //This does not enforce uniqueness
    private U2 u2;

}

@Entity
@Table(
    name = "u2",
    uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(name = "p1", columnNames = {"p1"})
    }
)
public class u2
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String p1; //Uniqueness is enforced here

}
```

Creating and updating the entities by

```
t1 t1_0 = new t1("t1_0");
t1 t1_1 = new t1("t1_1");
u2 u2_0 = new u2("u2_0");

repository.save(t1_0);
repository.save(t1_1);
repository.save(u2_0);

t1_0 = repository.findOne(t1_0.getId());
t1_1 = repository.findOne(t1_1.getId());

t1_0.setu2(u2_0);
t1_1.setu2(u2_0);
```

After the transaction finishes t1_0.u2 is tied to u2_0 and t1_1.u2 is tied to u2_0. I expected that it would throw uniqueness constraint violation exception.

Do not understand what is wrong. Other threads on SO suggest that `@JoinColumn(unique = true)` should do it.

**EDIT**
This is wrapped in one transaction

```
t1_0 = repository.findOne(t1_0.getId());
t1_1 = repository.findOne(t1_1.getId());

t1_0.setu2(u2_0);
t1_1.setu2(u2_0);
```

**EDIT2**

For some reason I can't access the database either. The console view loads but after adding password and user blank page is shown (some network queries fail).

But I can see from log that foreign keys are created and unique constraint aswell

```
Hibernate: alter table driver add constraint UK_ssh305wwvomjtn6opolug33nj unique (cardo_id)

Hibernate: alter table car add constraint FKosnia01vhqwmm888uxrg4o6f6 foreign key (manufacturerdo_id) references manufacturer

Hibernate: alter table driver add constraint FK3yb5ci9sr6ieo6n4wwwef3puv foreign key (cardo_id) references car
```

When adding

Comment: How did you generate your database tables?

Comment: After these lines t1_0.setu2(u2_0);t1_1.setu2(u2_0); did you update the saved them in the database? (the t1_0 and t1_1)? What is the code after these lines?

Comment: After the lines daos get autocommitted? I do not call save explicitly, some spring magic happens there since after the transaction closes data gets persisted from dao to table.

Comment: @Noripsni Do the data in the database populated with the data that you expect, with the duplicate data?What the tables t1 and u2 contain?

Comment: It gets populated with correct data (u2_0) in this case. u2_0 PK is the same on both objects (t1_0 and t1_1).

Comment: Go back and tell people what is the SCHEMA that was GENERATED. JPA will NEVER enforce "uniqueness" in memory. Those annotations are used to generate the schema

Comment: If I remove ´@UniqueConstraint(name = "uc_username2", columnNames = {"cardo_id"})´  no unique constrant gets added

Comment: something weird is happening here. I removed `@Transactional` from my test and added repository.save(obj) to the code after that I started to get unique constrain failure. None of the other combinations between these two do no work only if `@Transactional` is removed and .save is added.

Answer (score 0):

My transactions were invalid. As they do not see each others data, I mistakenly created one within another.

Answer (score -1):

Columns names (if more than one) should be introduced with commas. 
Your convention is wrong

Disclaimer: not checked on real database

```
@Table(
    name = "t1",
    uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(name = "u1", columnNames = {"u1"}),
            @UniqueConstraint(name = "u2", columnNames = {"u2", "id"}) // comma    
                        }

)
```